# Rspec not logging user in for tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to test the 'CREATE' method of my controller to redirect to the root_url upon success.

```
# templates_controller.rb

require 'open-uri'

class TemplatesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user! # Authenticate for users before any methods are called

  def create
    @template = current_user.templates.build(params[:template])
    if @template.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully uploaded the file."

      if @template.folder #checking if we have a parent folder for this file
        redirect_to browse_path(@template.folder) #then we redirect to the parent folder
      else
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

And this is my spec file

```
describe "POST 'create'" do    

  let(:template) { mock_model(Template) }

  before(:each) do
    controller.stub_chain(:current_user, :templates, :build) { template }
  end

  context "success" do
    before(:each) do
      template.should_receive(:save).and_return(true)
      post :create
    end

    it "sets flash[:notice]" do
      flash[:notice].should == "Successfully uploaded the file."
    end

    it "redirects to the root_url" do
      response.should redirect_to(root_url)
    end

  end
end
```

this is the error that i get

```
   TemplatesController POST 'create' success sets flash[:notice]
   Failure/Error: flash[:notice].should == "Successfully uploaded the file."
     expected: "Successfully uploaded the file."
          got: nil (using ==)
   # ./spec/controllers/templates_controller_spec.rb:35:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

12) TemplatesController POST 'create' success redirects to the root_url
   Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(root_url)
     Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/users/sign_in>
   # ./spec/controllers/templates_controller_spec.rb:39:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

13) Template should be valid
   Failure/Error: Template.new.should be_valid
     expected valid? to return true, got false
   # ./spec/models/template_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The test obviously isn't logging a user in since it redirects to http://test.host/users/sign_in. How can I get rspec to log the user in?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what #authenticate_user! is doing, but my guess is your mocking over top of some portion of authentication with:

```
controller.stub_chain(:current_user, :templates, :build) { template }
```

Another possibility is you're being redirected due to another filter earlier, for example a filter that redirects if ActiveRecord::NotFound.  I would suggest replacing mocks/expectations with real calls until you isolate the issue.

You might also take a look at Devise, specifically Devise::TestHelpers#sign_in for inspiration on authentication testing.

Comment: what would be some examples of calls i could use instead of mocks/expectations?

Comment: Try inserting the specs you created for testing #authenticate_user!, i.e. actually post to the controller real authentication data to log the test user in